# Uploading two versions of apk simultaneously having same code base but different signature

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, release

How can I make the same application have two Apk versions with different signatures, so both can be uploaded to the Play Store independently, with different features.

For example, one Apk is a free version have half features and the other is a paid version with full features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use flavors. More information:
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

In this example you have 2 flavors:

```
productFlavors {
    pro {
        applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.pro"
    }
    free {
        applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.free"
    }
}
```

So, if you go to Android Studio to "Build Variants" panel you can choose which version compile.
The advantage is that with only one click you can compile the version you want. If not, you have to maintain 2 separately apps.

Answer (score 0):

## Use `applicationIdSuffix`

An easier way is to add `applicationIdSuffix` to non-default buildTypes. This is helpful for debugging, but shouldn't be used for Play Store uploads or the `debug` buildType.

```
buildTypes {
    myVariant {
        debuggable true
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
    ...
}
```

This will end up making the debug version be `com.my.package.debug`, so both can be installed simultaneously.